Shopify Liquid-Filtering in Liquid
So I am doing  {%- for filter in collection.filters -%} to access the filter options set using search and discovery app in shopify liquid in collections page but i want to access it in header of my webpage how to do it. it is not accessing it in my header with is actually a snippet in my theme. Does anyone have anyidea about the same.
{%- for filter in collection.filters -%} not getting it in sidebar of the navbar and i want to do the filtering through header sidebar as is the requirement of the design
